# Django filter the queryset of ModelChoiceField - what did i do wrong?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I know that many questions exist about this same topic, but i am confused on one point.
My intent is to show two ModelChoiceFields on the form, but not directly tie them to the Game model.

I have the following:

**forms.py**

```
class AddGame(forms.ModelForm):
    won_lag = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[('1','Home') , ('2', 'Away') ])
    home_team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Player.objects.all())
    away_team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Player.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = ('match', 'match_sequence')
```

**Views.py**

```
def game_add(request, match_id):
    game = Game()
    try:
        match = Match.objects.get(id=match_id)
    except Match.DoesNotExist:
        # we have no object!  do something
        pass

    game.match = match

    # get form
    form = AddGame(request.POST or None, instance=game)
    form.fields['home_team'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team=match.home_team )

    # handle post-back (new or existing; on success nav to game list)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # redirect to list of games for the specified match
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('nine.views.list_games'))

    ...
```

Where i am confused is when setting the queryset filter.
First i tried:

```
form.home_team.queryset = Player.objects.filter(team=match.home_team )
```

but i got this error

```
AttributeError at /nine/games/new/1 
'AddGame' object has no attribute 'home_team'
...
```

so i changed it to the following: (after reading other posts)

```
form.fields['home_team'].queryset = Player.objects.filter(team=match.home_team )
```

and now it works fine.

So my question is, what is the difference between the two lines? Why did the second one work and not the first?  I am sure it is a newbie (i am one) question, but i am baffled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django Forms are `metaclasses`:

```
>>> type(AddGame)
<class 'django.forms.forms.DeclarativeFieldsMetaclass'>
```

They basically create a form instance according to the information given in its definition. This means, you won't get exactly what you see when you define the `AddGame` form. When you instantiate it, the `metaclass` will return the proper instance with the fields provided:

```
>>> type(AddGame())
<class 'your_app.forms.AddGame'>
```

So, with the instance, you can access the fields by simply doing `form.field`. In fact, it is a bit more complicated than that. There are two types of fields you can access. With `form['field']` you'll be accessing a [`BoundField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField). Which is used for output and raw_input.

By doing `form.fields['fields']` you'll be then accessing to a [*field that python can understand*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/). This is because if the from already got any input, there's where validation and data conversion take places (in fact, those are the fields used for this, [the general process of validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) is a bit more complicated).

I hope this might clear a little the issue for you but as you may see, the whole [form's API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/) is really big and complicated. Is very simple for end-users but it has a lot of programming behind the curtains :)

Reading the links provides will help clear your doubts and will improve your knowledge about this very useful topic and Django in general.

Good luck!

**UPDATE:** By the way, if you want to learn more about Python's Metaclasses, [this is a **hell of an answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python?lq=1) about the topic.

Answer (score 0):

In you `views.py`, you have this line:

```
form = AddGame(request.POST or None, instance=game)
```

So `form` is a Form object of class `AddGame` (Side note: you should change the name to `AddGameForm` to avoid confusion).

Since `home_team` is a field in `AddGame` class, it's not an attribute in `form` object. That's why you can't access it via `form.home_team`.

However, Django Form API provides `fields` attribute to any form object, which is a dict contains all form fields. That's why you can access `form.fields['home_team']`.

And finally since `home_team` is a `ModelChoiceField`, it can contain a `queryset` attribute, that's why you can access `form.fields['home_team'].queryset`